# Spring boot stomp sends RECEIPT frame multiple times

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I am developing a chat application with Stomp and Rabbitmq on Spring Boot.

When a client sends a message to the server (Spring Boot), the server saves the message to a database and then sends the message to its recipient.

What I would like to do is to send a `RECEIPT` frame with `message-id` to the clients when they send a message to let them know that their messages have been saved to the database.

I can send the `RECEIPT` frame from the `afterMessageHandled()`  of `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` class. But it sends the same `RECEIPT` frame multiple times like three times.

So the clients receive the same `RECEIPT` frame three times for a single message.

This is my `ChannelInterceptor` which saves the message to the database in `presend()`

```
public class StompChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

@Autowired
private ChatService chatService;

@Autowired
private CompositeMessageConverter compositeMessageConverter;


@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, @NonNull MessageChannel channel) {
    MessageHeaders messageHeaders = message.getHeaders();
    StompHeaderAccessor stompHeaderAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    StompCommand stompCommand = stompHeaderAccessor.getCommand();

    if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(stompCommand)) {
        //validate subscribe
    } else if (StompCommand.SEND.equals(stompCommand)) {
        System.out.println("presend!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        ChatMessageDTO chatMessageDTO =
                (ChatMessageDTO) compositeMessageConverter.fromMessage(message, ChatMessageDTO.class);
        chatService.validateAndSaveMessage(chatMessageDTO);
    }
    return message;
}
}
```

This is my `MessageMapping` function which handles the incoming messages

```
@MessageMapping("/chat/send")
public void send(@Payload ChatMessageDTO chatMessageDTO, MessageHeaders messageHeaders) {
    System.out.println("send!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, chatMessageDTO);
}
```

And lastly, this is my `ExecutorChannelInterceptor` which sends the `RECEIPT` frame in `afterMessageHandled()`

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(chatChannelInterceptor());

    registration.interceptors(new ExecutorChannelInterceptor() {

        @Override
        public void afterMessageHandled(Message<?> inMessage,
                                        MessageChannel inChannel, MessageHandler handler, Exception ex) {

            StompHeaderAccessor inAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(inMessage);

            if (StompCommand.SEND.equals(inAccessor.getCommand())) {

                System.out.println("afterMessageHandled");

                if (outChannel != null) {
                    StompHeaderAccessor outAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.RECEIPT);
                    outAccessor.setSessionId(inAccessor.getSessionId());
                    outAccessor.setReceiptId(receipt);
                    outAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
                    outAccessor.setMessageId(inAccessor.getMessageId());

                    Message<byte[]> outMessage =
                            MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], outAccessor.getMessageHeaders());

                    outChannel.send(outMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

If I run this code, I have got this log, which indicates that `afterMessageHandled()` is called three times.

```
presend!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
afterMessageHandled!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
afterMessageHandled!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
send!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
afterMessageHandled!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

So, questions are

1. Is there any way to send a RECEIPT frame to clients **only once** right after `presend()` please because I'd like to send the RECEIPT frame after confirming that the message has been saved to the database which happens in `presend()`?
2. Is it possible to change payload or headers in `presend()` please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that each call to afterHanldedMessage() comes with different handlers. So you can do what you want based on different handlers. You might want to do If(handler instanceof SomeHandlerClass).